# Is there a way to open file dialog in python without using Tkinter

Tags: python, windows, file, explorer

Like the title says, I need to have a way for python to open up that file dialog option, preferably filtering for a single file extension, then return whatever file was chosen.

I've been looking online and Tkinter seems like the only option, I want to keep this code as self contained as possible (only imported os and pygame so far), and was wondering if file dialog is possible without any imports (except os, if theres an os method that's fine).

This is the kind of implementation I'm looking for:

`filePath = filedialog(extension=".athdb")`

Comment: Seriously what is going on with python!? Every single module I've found that can do file dialog is a module for GUI, is there not some normal method to do it (like how open() is just a simple built-in function).

Comment: The file dialog is a GUI element, so it makes sense that it would be in a GUI library. Also, tkinter is in the standard library so it shouldn't really be a problem to use as a dependency.

Comment: I thought the file dialog was something within windows' operating system that programs just call on. The reason I didn't want to use Tkinter was because I'd have to have a withdrawn window the whole time and it just felt unneccesary and wasteful.

Comment: According to the tkinter docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename), askopenfilename and similar create a filedialog.open object, which it suggests to be a native handle. This means it can be used without a window root, so you don't have to worry about that running in the background.

Comment: Thank you!!! Do you know if this thing is specific to tkinter or if tkinter is just calling some buried windows function... I don't really understand how operating systems interact with python so if this question is dumb/misinformed please tell me.

Comment: I had a bit of a dig through the code and I think it eventually calls a windows function but tkinter is too complicated so I'm not sure. Tkinter should be cross compatible with other platforms so it is likely that they use native functions.

Comment: Thanks for checking, shame the source code is so complex. You've been helpful.